# GWT Maven Archetype in Eclipse - Unknown output directory

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, m2eclipse, gwt-maven-plugin

I've created a new Maven project using the gwt-maven-plugin archetype in Eclipse Juno.
After creating the project I get a build error:

> Unknown   Google Web App Problem: The output directory for the project
>   should be set to /myproject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did you verify whether the issue is related to https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3583

Comment: Just go through this too - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/0HZF47T6ono

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project|Properties|Google|Web Application. Uncheck the checkbox (Launch and deploy from this directory ...).

See http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-use-google-plugin-for-eclipse.html